# Replace only "CRLF" in string having both "CRLF" and "LF" line-separator

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string containing both "CRLF" and "LF" as line separator.

I want to replace only "CRLF" with " LF" (space and LF) and keeping "LF" as it is.

I know,we can do this using regex, but I have tried few regex from the already existing answers, but not able to resolve.

Please help, I am new to the javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Can you please provide the string and the code you have tried. Also tag please your question properly with regex and remove any tags if needed.

Comment: You should post your regexp.      
Basically -> CR => \r LF => \n     
Then :      
`var regexp_clean_CRLF = new RegExp("\r\n", "g");`     
`my_string = my_string.replace(regexp_clean_CRLF, " \n")`

Comment: I cannot upload any input data right now as am in office and upload is banned, will upload the screenshot of the input string.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As simple as

```
the_string.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
```

where `\r` is the escape sequence for `CR` and `\n` is the one for `LF` and `g` is a regex modifier to replace all matching instances instead of only the first one found.

Comment: If the first parameter to replace is a string instead of a regex, it will only replace the first occurrence.